# Database creation in Azure from bacpac

Tags: database, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, bacpac

While creating a database in `Azure` from a `bacpac` we receive the following error. We have tried a number of times with different containers/storage accounts

```
BadRequest &lt;string xmlns=&#34;
http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/&#34;&gt;Error encountered during the service operation. ; 
Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:
Unable to authenticate request; &lt;/string&gt;
```

We have used the following variations:

1. Change of names
2. Change of service tiers
3. Change of bacpac even those from earlier created dbs
4. Able to create blank database

Any help?

Comment: At first glance this looks like you haven't provided the SQL Authentication for your server admin login. How are you trying to import the database, through Portal.Azure.com, Manage.windowsazure.com, PowerShell, or REST API?